# Constructing a string from a large chunk of HTML

Tags: c#

Just wondering if there is an easy way around my issue. If I want to place a large chunk of HTML into a string, how's it possible without escaping the HTML first? There is so much HTML which is used for my MySpace bot (inserting into profiles) that it will take forever to escape.

Comment: MySpace bot sounds like an infringement of their [**terms of use**](http://www.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=misc.terms): Prohibited is " any automated use of the system, such as, but not limited to, using scripts to add friends or send comments, messages, status or mood updates, blogs or bulletins;"

Comment: Yeah he probably shouldn't have mentioned that but the question itself is relevant enough ("how to deal with large blocks of HTML").

Answer (score 3):

Following what @MattMitchell suggested, you can include the file as a resource in your project. Then you only have to reference it (`MyNameSpace.Properties.Resources.MyHTMLFile`) to get the contents as a string.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't. But you can use a verbatim string literal (prefixed with @) to make your life slightly easier - you'd only have to replace " with "" to escape the string.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm using atm. Ah well. I'll continue to escape the characters :(

Unless, I had the HTML stored in text file. But that wouldn't all me to insert variables into the HTML ... would it?

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a file, load the file.

Example:

```
string myHTML;
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("path.txt", FileMode, FileAccess))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        myHTML = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

If you want to insert variables into your HTML, replace the variable locations with {0} .. {n} and then use string.Format();

E.g.

```
<html><div>{0} = {1}</div></html>
```

and in your C#

```
string myHTMLwithVars = string.Format(myHTML, var1, var2);
```

Alternatively (and more manageable if there are lots of variables or the order is likely to change), name each "variable spot" in your HTML and use string replace.

```
<html><div>{username} = {randomImageFile}</div></html>
```

c# change:

```
string myHTMLwithVars = myHTML
    .Replace("{username}", usernameVar)
    .Replace("{randomImageFile}", "image.jpg");
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add placeholders in the text file so I can add dynamic data?

Like
    String.Format(filetext, "Fred", "Jack", "HelloWorld!");

Comment: Yep and see latest change if you want named placeholders. If this answer meets your needs please remember to hit the "tick" to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read this HTML from a file, or an embedded resource in your project? That way no escaping is necessary.

to read from file:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText("path/to/file.htm");
```

Comment: Did not know there was a File.ReadAllText method, very handy!